# Select2 items show by if clause

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a problem about select2 I want when user login who show just id "A"' text or select2 will be lock and user show only "A"'text but when admin login who show select2' all items(A and B texts) but how can I do this I don't know.

my code block:

```js
var tahsilatData = [{
  id: "A",
  text: 'AÇIK TAHSİLAT'
}, {
  id: "B",
  text: 'SADECE BLOKE KREDİ KARTI İLE'
}];

$('#AcenteTahsilat').select2({
  placeholder: "Tahsilat Seçeneği",
  data: tahsilatData,
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group m-form__group">
  <label for="AcenteTahsilat">Tahsilat Şekli :</label>
  <div id="AcenteTahsilatInfo" class="input-group m-input-group">
    <select class="form-control m-select2 m-select2-general w-100" id="AcenteTahsilat" name="AcenteTahsilat" style="width: 100%">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've turned your code into a runnable snippet, and added the following dependencies: jQuery, Select2.js, Select2.css. If this is incorrect, please rollback my edit. That said, we can't really answer your question without knowing the logic you're using to distinguish a user from an admin.

Comment: It appears that English is not your native language, that is OK however your question as stated is difficult to understand.  Please provide a bit more clarity in your expected results here.

Comment: it doesn't matter you can put if clause anywhere like if user id ='1' tahsilatData's first element lock else show A and B